# Reporting services: why is there all this blank space at the start of my chart?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, report-designer

I'm developing a RDLC report using Reporting Services, and I have a column chart that looks like this in the editor:

[image]

As you can see, there is a lot of blank space on the left of the chart. And in fact, when rendered the chart looks like this on a PDF page:

[image]

How to I reduce that left padding? I don't see any relevant options anywhere, not in the chart area nor in the axis properties, there's no option to set a width for the various elements of the chart. What am I missing?

Comment: Its hard to tell without some sample data to reproduce but I would try setting the vertical axis min and max values to fixed values (0 and 1 or 0 and 100 depending on the type of value), also try setting the x-axis labels to be vertical to see if that has an influence. Finally you can check the 'CustomPosition` and `CustomInnerPlotPosition` properties of the `Chart Area` object (not the parent chart object)

Comment: @AlanSchofield: `CustomPosition` and `CustomInnerPlotPosition` are exactly what I was looking for! If you rewrite this comment as an actual answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Done and glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell without some sample data to reproduce but I would try setting the vertical axis min and max values to fixed values (0 and 1 or 0 and 100 depending on the type of value), also try setting the x-axis labels to be vertical to see if that has an influence.

Finally you can check the 'CustomPosition` and CustomInnerPlotPosition properties of the Chart Area object (not the parent chart object)

Comment: CustomPosition and CustomInnerPlotPosition did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The Side Margin property on the Horizontal Axis property page controls the padding of the chart. Right-click on the axis and click on Properties on the drop down menu to get to the Axis properties.

[image]

When the Side Margin property is changed to Disabled, the bars will move to the left side.

[image]